# Rails Drag and Drop Elements (List/Grid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a Rails application which requires Drag and Drop sorting. I am a newbie to Rails. Kindly share some strp-by-step tutuorials or please give me answers here. 
I referred : [sortable bootstrap table](http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/) and [Ajax Rails Sortable List with rails 4](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/ajax-sortable-lists-rails-4). I tried to follow them step by step, but some initial code was not given, so I couln't write a Rails app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails guide for Sortable Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314547/rails-guide-for-sortable-lists)

Comment: What have tried so far? Please show us what you got. On which point did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use rails_sortable but it will not support rails 5 if you want to use rails 5 then i advise you to use **[html5sortable](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/)**

for rails 4 please refer my demo on rails_sortable using below link

**[Click here](https://github.com/raxit2009/sortable_draganddrop_grid)**